# What is the login username and password for VNC access

Tags: openstack, vnc

I want to use OpenStack VNC console for my instance. The console asks the login credentials in to start. What is normally user name and password for the instance.

Note: I did not give any password when when I created the instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default users on our Linux instances are not preconfigured with a password. Until a password is set you will not be able to login to your instance via the VNC console. We recommend setting up a password for the default user, or a new user with login access as part of the initial instance configuration process.

Answer (score 1):

For the first time login it is recommended that you generate a key-pair (In ubuntu, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys) and inject into the image (http://docs.openstack.org/grizzly/basic-install/yum/content/basic-install_operate.html) and do SSH to the instance using the key-pair.
Once you are logged in, you can create a user and using this user you can login through VNC console.